# Transfer of data to the new mysql database with the changed tables

Tags: mysql

I would like to move the data from the current database to the new database with the revised schametem: tables have different kinase fields and some of tables do not exist, etc. ..
How to perform this operation quickly and painlessly? ;)

Comment: By creating a script that will map old schema to a new one.

Comment: yes I know. but it is time-consuming and I hope that there is a faster way :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no feature to move data from database to new database. We only can move data from table to table. If you want to move data from database to new database, just copy you database to the new one. Then, you can revised schema from new database. No operation can be perform quickly in this case.